# Use OpenGL to draw shader to a stream?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on this photo app that uses OpenGL 2.0 with a Renderer, an off-screen GLSurfaceView and some shader scripts (*.fsh and *.vsh).

after loading the shader scripts from Assets folder, preparing the GL surface and context, etc, etc we finally call `GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);` and it works quite nicely and it generates the bitmaps with the effects.

The problem, OF COURSE, is the memory limitations and any large enough bitmap (regardless of device, not so big for old Gingerbread and very large images for the Nexus 10) and it will produce and OutOfMemoryException.

I'm not so knowledgeable in OpenGL and the way I know to deal with very large amounts of data is to use a stream so it's not necessary to hold it all in memory.

So the question is, is there a way to do apply an openGl shader/renderer through a Stream instead of a in-memory Bitmap ? If yes, any pointer to a link or base procedure?

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, I'm a beginner in OpenGl, how do you draw shaders offscreen? as I understood from the documentation rendering to a GLSurfaceView should only succeed if it's visible.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by `Stream` but here's another solution. Split rendering up into multiple passes. Fore instance, if you have a 512x512 texture and a corresponding quad to texture but can only afford to upload a 256x256 due to memory restrictions do the following:

- split up the texture into 4 chunks
- create a single, fitting texture object
- for each chunk

  - upload the current chunk into the tex objects data store
  - draw 1/4 of the quad, e.g. top-left and texture accordingly

Note that the above example assume a 512x512 texture and screen-size. In any case, I think you get the idea.

Obviously, this is the usual memory/performance trade-off.You circumvent memory restrictions by using more bandwidth for transfers and do more rendering.

Note: I'm a desktop GL guy and I'm not quite sure how memory is split up betweem the GPU and the rest, or if there even is some dedicated VRAM. I assume you've got a limited amount available for GL resources which is even smaller than the overall system memory.

Comment: hi. Thanks for the input. I meant an InputStream, or (to be more precise) FileInputStream. It's an interesting idea you gave and I'll take a look at it for sure. The memory is the same used for the whole Java VM.

Comment: @Budius: If you can load parts of the texture using the stream classes, you can just as easily load a set of lines from the image directly from an SD card or internal memory and upload that to the texture object.